# How can i send two values from the same select option to a url in php?

Tags: php, html

I have this code

```
                   <form method="post" action="">
                    <select name="gender">
                      <option value="">Select a person:</option>
                      <option value="Male" id="boy">Male</option>
                      <option value="Female" id="girl">Female</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" name="subgen" value="Find">
                   </form>
```

and i want to try and send two values through url With  this php code

```
                  <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['subgen'])) {
                      $gender =$_POST['gender'];
                      //i want to get the id to go along too
                      ?><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=genderreport.php?gender=<?php echo ($gender) && genderid=<?php echo ($genderid); ?>"/><?php                    
                    }
                  ?>
```

and i want to get it through this in another page:

```
  if(isset(($_GET['gender'])&&($_GET['genderid'])){
    $gender= $_GET['gender'];
    $genderid= $_GET['genderid'];
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just need the ID?  If this is coming from a database then you can use the ID to get the text.  Why would you need two values which essentially contain the same information?

Comment: This is a syntax error `if(isset(($_GET['gender'])&&($_GET['genderid'])){`

Comment: Yeah, I question why even the redirect at all. Just post that gender var to the final php and split it there. This all screams "no planning".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you're trying to achieve (why you do redirect instead of direct submit to second file), but still:

```
 <select name="gender">
     <option value="">Select a person:</option>
     <option value="Male:boy">Male</option>
     <option value="Female:girl">Female</option>
 </select>
```

On server side split the value by `:`:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['subgen'])) {
    $parts = explode(':',  $_POST['gender']);?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=genderreport.php?gender=<?php echo $parts[0]?>&genderid=<?php echo $parts[1]?>"/>
<?php
}
```

In **another** page:

```
if (isset($_GET['gender']) && isset($_GET['genderid'])) {
    $gender= $_GET['gender'];
    $genderid= $_GET['genderid'];
}
```

Note, please use spaces in your code, it greatly increases readability.

Answer (score 1):

You need to end the first `<?php echo $gender;` before you can do another `<?php echo $genderid;`. There's no need for `&&` between them.

```
?><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=genderreport.php?gender=<?php echo $gender; ?>&genderid=<?php echo $genderid; ?>"/><?php
```